# Define setter/getter attributes for a 3D array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, getter-setter

In c++, I have a class that contains a 3d array of defined type. I need to define several attributes that have a value of int and be able to set and get the attributes for 3d array.

```
    //header;
    class Voxel
    {
      private:
        vector< vector < vector < myPoints* > > > Vox; // 3D array
      public:
        //... 
     };

     //Here is the constructor and methods of the class:
     Voxel::Voxel(myType var1; double var2)
     {
     // this is constructor

     }
```

For example I need to define "Attributes" like this which have int values:

```
Attributes:
LabelTag; // Vox tag e.g. an int tag=2
NumberofPoints; // Vox nr of containing points e.g. int nr=5


Vox.setAttribute(LabelTag tag, Value 2);
Vox.setAttribute(NumberofPoints nr, Value 5);

int tag        = Vox.getAttribute(LabelTag);
int nrofpoints = Vox.getAttribute(NumberofPoints);
```

How should I define the attributes, as struct or as a typedef or something else, and then how may I set the values to my 3D array members e.g. Vox,
I want to set attributes to the Vox itself, not the points inside? Is it possible?
And should them defined as private or public?

Comment: You store pointers, so to access them you use the "arrow" syntac `Vox[i][j][k]->getAttribute()`

Comment: Please tell us, what is the usage of LabelTag and NumberOf Points? You can store one Point per Vector, so you have 3 Points in one 3d array.

Comment: @pospich0815, it's and attempt at clever (maybe) use of tag dispatch. A template specialization may be better `getAttribute<Label>()`.

Comment: @StoryTeller, I edited my question, so I need attributes to be set for Vox not to the points inside the vector. If I do Vox[i][j][k]->getAttribute() then it get attributes from myPoints, which is not I expect.

Comment: `Vox` **is** a vector (of vectors). It's defined by the standard, you can't change its definition. If you want extra parameters associated with it, store it in `Voxel`, that's the whole point of wrapping `Vox`. And your example is still very confusing. If you do `Vox[i][j][k]` you access a point, not the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited answer below the second block of code.

Ok, firstly as commented by @StoryTeller, your vector is storing pointers; so you will need to use the -> syntax to access the object they are pointing to.

So you should probably setup a myPoints class as structs are not commonly seen (structs in c++ are the same thing as a class except the default access modifier to their properties and functions is public). I'd imagine this class to look something like

```
class myPoints // you should probably split this into a header and cpp
{
    int tag;
    int noOfPoints;

    myPoints() : tag(0), noOfPoints(0) // construct with whatever values, you can pass your own
    {}

    void setNoOfPoints(noOfPoints)
    {
        this->noOfPoints = noOfPoints;
    }

    void setTag(tag)
    {
        this->tag = tag;
    }

    int getNoOfPoints(){ return noOfPoints; }
    int getTag(){ return tag; }
};
```

Assuming you've initialized vox with some *myPoints literals you can then simply access and use your myPoints objects as follows

```
int tag = Vox.at(i).at(j).at(k)->getTag();
int noOfPoints = Vox.at(i).at(j).at(k)->getNoOfPoints();

Vox.at(i).at(j).at(k)->setNoOfPoints(6);
Vox.at(i).at(j).at(k)->setTag(6);
```

Leaving the above answer, as with @Aconcagua's answer, you might find it useful in the future.

Anyway, I think I understand a little better what you are trying to do, given the code you have already written as @StoryTeller has said, you can just use your Voxel class to hold the tag and noOfPoints properties for each vector. The Voxel class will look something like (forgive my laziness in not providing a header)

```
class Voxel
{
private:
    vector< vector < vector < myPoints* > > > Vox; 

    int tag;
    int noOfPoints;
public:
    Voxel() : tag(0), noOfPoints(0) // construct with whatever values, you can pass your own
    {}

    vector< vector < vector < myPoints* > > >& getVox(){ return Vox; } //Ignore my shitty naming scheme, you can use this to set or get elements

    void setNoOfPoints(noOfPoints)
    {
        this->noOfPoints = noOfPoints;
    }

    void setTag(tag)
    {
        this->tag = tag;
    }

    int getNoOfPoints(){ return noOfPoints; }
    int getTag(){ return tag; } 
};
```

and then to access your vector and set your tag and noOfPoints, simply create an instance of Voxel, it should look something like this

```
//A new vector of voxels

vector<Voxel> voxels;

voxels.push_back(Voxel); // this only needs to be a 1d array, you can construct each voxel however you like and add as many as you like

//settting the tag for the first element

voxels[0].setTag(0);

//getting the tag for the first element 

int tag = voxels[0].getTag();

// manipulating the contained vector 

voxels[0].getVox().at(i).at(j).at(k) = //whatever you are storing in your vector
```

Comment: this answer is close to what i need, but as I edited the question, is it possible to assign these attributes to the Vox itself not the points inside. Because myPoints may have different values per point, but Vox that contains these myPoints can get one value per "Attribute". Or imagine some of the Vox are empty but still i can assign some attributes to them.

Comment: It is possible! Infact as was pointed out you were on the right lines with your Voxel class, I've edited my answer, hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, I implemented your code and it is quite close to what I'm looking for. Just I don't understand one important thing, when I'm assigning e.g. "tag attribute" with `i_Voxel.setTag(6)` it sets it to what?!! I assume to an instance of `Voxel` but how should i know to which vector of Vox it has been set. Let's say I have a loop through all vectors and want to set to each vector a tag. Could you explain how it work?

Comment: Sure, I think you mean each vector should have it's own attributes, right? So you can just create an array-like structure (even a vector) of instances of the Voxel class, that way the layout is fairly clean and each vector has associated attributes.                                                                                             In my example there is only one vector wrapped in the Voxel class and so i_Voxel.setTag(6) means that specific vector's tag is now 6.

Comment: yes exactly, so I store all vectors of Voxel class in an array(or vector, in a way that each member has its own attribute and then return it as output of a method, so far so good. But when I want to use gettag() for each member how should i access the members of this array (or vector) using i,j,k. I add a sample code to my question. You can see the method I wrote.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the last block of my code, hopefully it makes things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Seeing George Purcell's answer, I might have misunderstood you question, thought it was about accessing the points from outside the Voxel class...

Instead of deleting the answer, though, I still leave it here for the case you run into this problem any *later* and find it useful *then*...

---

Apart from the pointer problem StoryTeller noted already, you have a little problem:

You could simply define an index operator, but this index operator then would be forced to return a reference to a `vector<vector<myPoints*>>` (one vector less) or a `vector<vector<vector<myPoints*>>>::iterator`.

This would, however, allow the user to modify the underlying vectors, e. g. clearing them. If you now returned const vector or const_iterator, the user would not be able to modify the stored value (calling setAttribute...). Additionally, he could cast the const away, at least in the first case, and then again do what he wanted...

So you have two options:

1. You write an explicit getter function:
   `mypoints* getPoints(int x, int y, int z) { return vox[x][y][z]; }`
2. You wrap the vectors into separate classes. Then each class can provide appropriate access to its underlying vector and at the same time prevent the user from doing illegal stuff. Each of this classes would then provide its own operator[], the same as will do your outer Voxel class:

```cpp
class Voxel
{
public:
    class Points1D
    {
        vector<myPoints*> points;
    public:
        myPoints* operator[](unsigned int index) { return points[index]; }
    };
    class Points2D
    {
        vector<Points1D> points;
    public:
        Points1D& operator[](unsigned int index) { return points[index]; }
    };
    Points2D& operator[](unsigned int index) { return points[index]; }
private:
    vector<Points2D> points;
};
```

If you want to be able to iterate over your classes, then you would have to provide appropriate iterators, too, and possibly other stuff (e. g. size() function), too - depending of what the user shall be able to do with your classes...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not a answer to your question but it looks like you've came from C#-kind world, so you let me clarify some things (I hope then you will be able to reformulate your question, so that ordinary c++ programmer could understand:)

The concept of attributes has completely different [meaning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60e6k732.aspx) in C++ (I think unrelated to what you want to implement)

Also there are no separate concept of properties (aka getters/setters) in C++.
Instead you just write getSmth() or setSmth(type arg) member functions.
Their purpose is just to give a user a controlled access to private member variables. However, these functions are just regular member function with now special abilities.

If you want to get/set a member variable say "tag" from class say "myPoint" you need to define a member function

```
class myPoint
{
 private:
    int tag;
//...
 public:
    int GetTag();
    {
       return tag; // return this->tag;
    }

    void SetTag(int t)
    {
       tag = t;
    }
}
```

Then you can write

```
int main()
{
   vector<vector<vector<myPoint*>>> Vox;
   Vox[1][2][3]->SetTag(10);
   cout << Vox[1][2][3]->GetTag();
}
```

However say you have a few getters/setter for different variables.
Then there is no way to write

```
Vox[1][2][3]->GetAtribute(tag);
```

and expect compiler to figure out that "oh, he needs to get a value of tag member variable".
In c++ class system there are only class member variables and member functions which can use them - everything as simple as that:)

Interesting thing is that you can parameterize any function not just with values, but also with types. Then you will be able to create a function template and call a different versions of the same function depending on which type you've set. You can use that to define for which attribute (indeed member variable) you want to call a getter or setter.

```
// LableTag is a class defined globally and GetAttribute() is a member
//template function
int i = Vox[1][2][3]->GetAttribute<LableTag>();
```

However, I haven't seen it being used for defining getters/setters. Usually if you want to "get something" you just write a concrete member function GetSomething();